# jQuery.length li with multiple ul

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get li.length on each ul on the site.
Now I get the total amount of all li's.(8)

I want it like this: `ul#1 : 4`   `ul#2 : 2`  `ul#3 : 2`

```
$( "li.first:contains('Brazil')" ).addClass( "correct" );
$( "li.second:contains('Croatia')" ).addClass( "correct" );
$( "li.third:contains('Mexico')" ).addClass( "correct" );
$( "li.fourth:contains('Cameroon')" ).addClass( "correct" );

var n = $("li.correct").length;
$( "#groupa" ).append( "<p>You got:  " + n + " points.</p>");
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sandviken/rZ9yB/) here

Comment: var n = $(".correct").length;

Comment: did not understand what exactly you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over each ul and then find li length in them using:

```
$('ul').each(function(){
  alert($('li',this).length);
     //or
  alert('ul#'+$(this).index()+':'+$('li',this).length);
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/agzDm/)**

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of "correct" classes:

> var n = $(".correct").length;

Comment: what's the different from OP: var n = $("li.correct").length;

Comment: because he is looking for li.first .correct, li.second .correct, li.third .correct li.fourth .correct, there is no $('li.correct'), ie, he is referencing it incorrectly and will never get the count because those objects don't exist. By just checking .correct, he gets everything he added the class "correct" to

Comment: However, OP's question is incomplete and doesn't contain the HTML markup, so I can understand why this answer may be incorrect application to their needs or that I understood it differently